# Добавить разделить между группами файлов

Tags: bash, unix, текст, awk, find

Сейчас у менять есть такой скрипт:
`find path -type f -exec md5sum {} + | uniq -D -w32`

Он выводит все файлы с одинаковой md5 суммой

**Пример вывода:**

```
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/1.txt
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/3.txt
```

Нужно чтобы группы с разной md5 имели разделитель ввиде пустой строки

**Пример нужного вывода:**

```
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/1.txt
5f0650b247a646355dfec2d2610a960c  ./levik/3.txt

8g0632b789a656235dzfg2d2610a732s  ./levik/4.txt
```

Думал использовать для это awk, но не смог придумать как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если [программа *uniq*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html) взята из пакета `coreutils` операционной системы *gnu*, то у неё есть встроенное средство разделения на группы. например:

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n1\n2' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate
1
1

2
2
```

p.s. как вы заметили, я использовал программу *sort* для сортировки строк, передаваемых программе *uniq*. это необходимое условие (цитата из документации):

> The input need not be sorted